# how to get last date from last year from a given date in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am looking for a solution to get from a date (timestamp), the last date of the previous year.
For Example

date = '2021-01-31' or '2021-04-25' . i expect '2020-12-31'

```
import pandas as pd
report_date = '2021-01-31'
report_date_tsmp = pd.Timestamp(report_date)
```

thanks for solutions!

Comment: the Gregorian calendar always runs from 1st Jan to 31 Dec so getting the last year doesn't even need any real logic, just string manipulation and a year offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
pd.Timestamp(f'12-31-{report_date_tsmp.year - 1}')
```

Less dirty with `offset`:

```
report_date_tsmp - pd.offsets.YearEnd()
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00')
```